# Bootstrap alert bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

You can visit the full code here: http://pastebin.com/ZyJG35aL

I started to make a test after the "else".

```
else {
  $('#route_update').click(function () {
    $('#comment').slideDown();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#comment').fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
  });
  return false;
}, 'json');
return false;
```

Using this code, seems that i've an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" so when i push the buttom, nothing works.

How can I do it working? Using Bootstrap and jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/gianluca/qxGT5/

Comment: Your JSFiddle seems to work fine once you select the JQuery framework instead of "No library".

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the indentation made the error more clear.  Remove the code within the `else` block and you have:

```
else {

}, 'json');
```

It's not clear from the code posted what you're *trying* to do, or what that `'json'` belongs to, but it certainly doesn't go after an `else` block.

Comment: I want to make the alert bar on the top of the table. Even If I leave the else till the ; i've Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: @user3754474: What does "leave the else till the ;" mean?  If you put a semi-colon after al `else` block that's also incorrect syntax.  An `else` block isn't a function or an object, it doesn't belong in a parameter list of a function call.

Comment: I made what you said but I still have an error

Comment: @user3754474: I can't help with code you don't show in the question.  Also, my answer doesn't *really* offer a correct course of action, since your intent isn't clear and the lines of code you show are entirely out of context.  All I'm able to do at this time is show you the syntax error in the code you've posted, which I've done.  If you have a more specific question, feel free to update your question or ask another.